# Java Streams Filtering Nested Collections by Min/Max

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<Integer, List<MyDayObject>>` that represents all days by week of year.
Now I need to analyze only the days that produced the highest value for each week. I have been able to get the nested streaming working with a `forEach` but I can't seem to be able to correctly stream it and `collect` into a `List` at the end.

```
weeks.forEach((k, v) -> { 
        MyDayObject highest = v.stream()
            .max((o1, o2) -> o1.value().compareTo(o2.value())).get();      
        System.out.println(highest);
    });
```

What I need though is not to print it but get a `List<MyDayObject> allHighest` at the end.

I tried `.filter`ing the `.entrySet()` by `.max()` but can't get that to work.
What's the best way to filter a `Map` by `max` of the nested `List`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need to map each value of the original Map to the corresponding max `MyDayObject`:

```
List<MyDayObject> allHighest = 
    weeks.values() // produces a Collection<List<MyDayObject>>
         .stream() // produces a Stream<List<MyDayObject>>
         .map(list -> list.stream() // transforms each List<MyDayObject> to a MyDayObject 
                                    // to obtain a Stream<MyDayObject>
                          .max((o1, o2) -> o1.value().compareTo(o2.value())).get())
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collects the elements to a List
```

P.S. I just copied your code that finds the maximum element of a given list without trying to improve it, which may be possible. I focused on getting the desired output.

As holi-java commented, the lambda expression that compares the elements can be simplified:

```
List<MyDayObject> allHighest = 
    weeks.values() 
         .stream() 
         .map(list -> list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MyDayObject::value)).get())
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ah, `map` it, not `filter` it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Care to elaborate on how to improve it as well?

Comment: @TommyF you can using `Comparator.comparing(MyDayObject::value)` instead.

Comment: @TommyF You got your answer from holi-java

Comment: Or without the unnecessary Stream operation: `Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(MyDayObject::value))`. Then, you don’t have to deal with `Optional`.